# 2d tile map is not displaying map on the screen using in android

Tags: android, andengine, tiles

I am using tiled to create map for my game.I am using AndEngine framework for developing games in android.In OnLoadResource method i am loading tmx file using load map method.When game builds,it throws "unfortunately stopped working" at this line.At first it shows, it cannot find images and i cleared that error.Now at this line game stops.Please help me because i am new to tile based games.

```
this.mTMXTiledMap = mTMXLoader.loadFromAsset(this,"tmx/levelmap.tmx");
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
private void loadMap() 
{
this.mRepeatingSpriteBackground = new   RepeatingSpriteBackground(CAMERA_WIDTH,CAMERA_HEIGHT, this.mEngine.getTextureManager(),new   AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource(this, mapBG), 1.0f);

try 
{
final TMXLoader mTMXLoader = new TMXLoader(this, this.mEngine.getTextureManager(),  TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA, null);

this.mTMXTiledMap = mTMXLoader.loadFromAsset(this,"tmx/levelmap.tmx");
} 
catch (final TMXLoadException tmxle) 
{
Debug.e(tmxle);
}
}
```

And here is the Logcat:

```
01-18 19:37:52.759: E/AndroidRuntime(643): java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
01-18 19:37:52.759: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at org.anddev.andengine.entity.layer.tiled.tmx.TMXTileSet.getTextureRegionFromGlobalTileID(TMXTileSet.java:154)
01-18 19:37:52.759: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at org.anddev.andengine.entity.layer.tiled.tmx.TMXTiledMap.getTextureRegionFromGlobalTileID(TMXTiledMap.java:193)
01-18 19:37:52.759: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at org.anddev.andengine.entity.layer.tiled.tmx.TMXLayer.addTileByGlobalTileID(TMXLayer.java:289)
01-18 19:37:52.759: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at org.anddev.andengine.entity.layer.tiled.tmx.TMXLayer.initializeTMXTilesFromDataString(TMXLayer.java:268)
01-18 19:37:52.759: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at org.anddev.andengine.entity.layer.tiled.tmx.TMXParser.endElement(TMXParser.java:193)
01-18 19:37:52.759: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.endElement(ExpatParser.java:156)
01-18 19:37:52.759: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.appendBytes(Native Method)
01-18 19:37:52.759: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:513)
01-18 19:37:52.759: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:474)
01-18 19:37:52.759: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:321)
01-18 19:37:52.759: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:279)
01-18 19:37:52.759: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at org.anddev.andengine.entity.layer.tiled.tmx.TMXLoader.load(TMXLoader.java:93)
01-18 19:37:52.759: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at org.anddev.andengine.entity.layer.tiled.tmx.TMXLoader.loadFromAsset(TMXLoader.java:78)
01-18 19:37:52.759: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at apk.games.robowars.RoboWars.loadMap(RoboWars.java:577)
01-18 19:37:52.759: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at apk.games.robowars.RoboWars.onLoadResources(RoboWars.java:248)
01-18 19:37:52.759: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.doResume(BaseGameActivity.java:168)
01-18 19:37:52.759: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onWindowFocusChanged(BaseGameActivity.java:85)
01-18 19:37:52.759: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onWindowFocusChanged(PhoneWindow.java:2423)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a problem with the file paths inside the TMX file. See [this](http://www.andengine.org/forums/development/tmx-tiled-map-divide-by-0-exception-t1244.html) and [this](http://www.andengine.org/forums/development/tmx-dividision-by-0-exeception-t1217.html) thread on the AndEngine forum for more detail.